# JAXB Moxy @XmlValueExtension provides a node name

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I'm trying to use @XmlValueExtension in a subclass, but the behavior is not as expected.

Root class is :

```
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@codeType")
@XmlSeeAlso({Subclass1.class})
public abstract class SuperClass {

}
```

Subclass is :

```
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Subclass1 extends SuperClass {

    @XmlValueExtension
    private String myValue;

}
```

But when marshalling, the XML result is :

```
<Superclass codeType="1">
   <myValue>my awesome value</myValue>
</Superclass>
```

I was expecting something like that :

```
<Superclass codeType="1">my awesome value</Superclass>
```

I'm using Moxy 2.6.3

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

OK, actually, we need to ADD @XmlValueExtension and not replace @XmlValue ;)

```
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Subclass1 extends SuperClass {

    @XmlValue
    @XmlValueExtension
    private String myValue;

}
```